# Spring stomp socket - ios client implemetation

Tags: ios, spring

I am creating an ios app that can interact with Spring stomp websocket, but I am not able to do so.

Java Code:

**configuration:**

```
<websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/app">
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/ws">
    </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
    <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic"/>
  </websocket:message-broker>
```

**Controller:**

```
@MessageMapping("/postMsg/{productId}")
@SendTo("/topic/subscribeMsg/{productId}")
public Message postComment(@DestinationVariable long productId, Message msg) throws Exception {
      ...
      return msg;
}
```

Comment: Hello did you solved your issue???